# Combining Subjects without waiting for each to emit

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I Have 4 Subjects that emit values on user Input

```
this.combine$ = zip(
  this.filterInputStore.selectedCurrenciesHandler,
  this.filterInputStore.searchInputHandler,
  this.filterInputStore.selectedTypesHandler,
  this.filterInputStore.selectedPrivacyOptionsHandler
).pipe(tap(() => { doSomething() }));
```

My Goal is to trigger the doSomething(), as soon as one of them emits a value.

Problem: All rxjs operators like zip or combineLatest require to wait until all subjects in it emit. This is extremely impractical if say i want to filter a list and want results even if i only use one filter.
Is there a rxjs best practise for this?

Comment: I don't think `merge` waits for all to emit. Otherwise you can `startWith` on each of them.

Comment: combineLatest doesn't wait for all of them to emit.

Comment: @FatihErsoy It does tho.

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković merge actually works in this case, thank you. write a reply so i can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe both `merge` or `race` would work. I prefer `race` because the method indicate that you're waiting for the first observable to emit (and win the race!). Also, `race` will trigger only ONCE, so your `doSomething` won't get executed multiple times.